# Get a php variable back after an AJAX action?

Tags: ajax

When I click onto a button of my page, I do the following action :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php?module=pages&action=afficher_page&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>", 
data:"vote="+vote,
success: function(){
alert("Vote done");
```

}

Then, the page of the url receive my POST variable to treat the vote:

```
<?php   
// I get the timestamp of the last user's vote
list($last_timestamp) = get_last_timestamp($_SESSION['id'], $_GET['id']);

// I get the server timestamp
$timestamp_click=time();

if($timestamp_click-$last_timestamp > $time_limit){ 
   $authorization_vote=false;
}else{
    $authorization_vote=true;
}
```

I would like to get back and send $autorisation_vote to AJAX or jQuery in order to alert the user if his vote has been done. I heard about callback but don't succeed to adapt to my case. How do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a couple of ways you could do it.

The quick and dirty way is to just echo "true" or "false" in your PHP and that will be available in to the callback function if you declare it like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?module=pages&action=afficher_page&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>", 
    data:"vote="+vote,
    success: function(data){
       alert(data);
    }
```

or you could set the http header to return a status code, which would allow you to declare two call backs in your ajax call on success or failure

The php would look like this

```
<?php   
// I get the timestamp of the last user's vote
list($last_timestamp) = get_last_timestamp($_SESSION['id'], $_GET['id']);

// I get the server timestamp
$timestamp_click=time();

if($timestamp_click-$last_timestamp > $time_limit){ 
    header("HTTP/1.0 423 Locked"); // The resource that is being accessed is locked
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Content"); // Processed, but not returning content
}
```

and your ajax call could look like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?module=pages&action=afficher_page&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>", 
    data:"vote="+vote,
    statusCode: {
       204: function(){ alert("Vote cast"); },
       423: function(){ alert("Vote not cast for whatever reason..."); }
    }
```

Which is probably a bit of overkill, but it's good to know these things.

Comment: The first way returns me the whole page html code in the alert. I'm going to try the second one, do you know if it's rather safe in term of security?

Comment: Is your PHP script outputting HTML as well as the "true,false" text? 


I can't think of any security concerns with either method, it's essentially the same method, just a bit more sophisticated. But if your script outputs anything before the header is set, you'll get an  output buffer error, so you'll need to put 'ob_start()' at the top of the script and you should change 204 to 200 because 204 means "No Content" and 200 just means "OK".

Comment: thanks, good to know. For my personal knowledge, do there is a third way to do what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php?module=pages&action=afficher_page&id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>", 
data:"vote="+vote,
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

(note added `data`)

and in your php script add

```
echo "vote done and some data here";
```

because `true` is changed to 1 and `false` would be blank

So example:

```
if($timestamp_click-$last_timestamp > $time_limit){ 
   $authorization_vote=false;
   echo "voted";
}else{
    $authorization_vote=true;
    echo "vote failed";
}
```